# Making a Doubly Linked list iterable

Tags: python, class, iterable

I can't figure out how to make my doubly linked list's iterableness work correctly when using nested loops.

My code thus far: http://pastebin.com/PU9iFggr

I have attempted to make it iterable:

```
def __iter__(self):
    self.index = 0
    return (self)

def next(self):
    try:
        result = self._findNode(self.index).get()
    except IndexError:
        self.index = 0
        raise StopIteration
    self.index += 1
    return result

def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self._findNode(item).get()
```

It seems to work if inside one for loop, but not inside of two:

```
myList = DoublyLinkedList()

myList.append(0)
myList.append(1)
myList.append(2)
myList.append(3)

for i in myList:
    print i         #works as expected

for i in myList:
    for j in myList:
        print j     #goes forever
```

I imagine that the issue is that there is only one self.index inside of the object that is being updated by both of the for loops, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Becuase your iterating over the same instance and using a single instance attribute to track your iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Container`s should be `Iterable`, not `Iterator`s. Don't implement `next` on the class itself. Either make `__iter__` a generator function, or write a separate class for it to return that wraps the linked list and implements `next`.

The easiest approach is to define `__iter__` as a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators):

```
def __iter__(self):
    cur = self.head
    while cur is not None:
        yield cur.value
        cur = cur.nextNode
```

Remove the `next` function from `DoubleLinkedList` and that's it. When you try to iterate it with a `for` loop, the call to the generator function returns a new, independent generator object which then iterates independently of any other generators that may have been requested. And it's much faster than repeated indexing like you were doing (which has to start from the `head` and traverse every time; the generator saves state as it goes, so it's only traversing one link in the chain for each item `yield`ed).

Answer (score 0):

I think you know very well where the problem is:

```
1 for i in mylist: 
2    for j in mylist:
3        print j
4    # when j loop ends index goes back 0, this is where the infinite
5    # loop is,next line in execution is 1, and the method called is
6    # "next()", it will read linkedlist[0] for the second time (and
7    # then repeat...forever)
```

in short every time you call **next** in **i** loop, it will just return doubleLinkedList[0], it make to progress towards the index exception.

There are a lot of solutions,
1. if all you do in the nested for loop is `print j`,you can simply just iterate through the length of your linkedlist:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)): # I see that you already have the __len__ method
    for j in mylist:
        print j
```

2.This is my favorite solution: Instead pf implementing an iterator interface,use **python generator**:

```
def traverseList(doubly_linked_list):
# select and delete all of your __iter__() and next(), use the following code
    index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield doubly_linked_list._findNode(index).get()
            index += 1
        except IndexError:
            break

for i in traverseList(mylist):
     for j in traverseList(mylist):
         # do things, note that I did not create two linked list
         # I sort of create two iterators...
```

you can look up **coroutine** if you are not too familiar with **generators**, but basically they have their own stack, so each iterator of your doubly linked list maintains its own **index** (what you try to achieve in your code)

3.hmmm I am still thinking, I will update if I got any new ideas